# Cakephp rendering view in Shell is not working

Tags: php, cakephp

Created a shell class, EmailShell which will render the html of given email template and pass it to Mandrill Api service.

```
App::uses('View', 'Core');
class EmailShell extends AppShell {
    function startup() {
        parent::startup();
        $useDbConfig = 'default';
    }

    function new_user_created(){
        $html = $this->getEmailTemplateHtml('new_user');
        $post_fields['message'] = array(
            "html" => $html,
            "text" => strip_tags($html),
            "from_email" => "from@example.com",
            "subject" => "subject goes here.",
            "to" => "to@example.com"
        );
        $Mandril = ClassRegistry::init("Mandril");
        $Mandril->sendEmail($post_fields);
    }

    private function getEmailTemplateHtml($template, $layout = 'default', $custom_data = false){
        $v = new View();
        $v->set("data", $custom_data);
        return $v->render('Emails/'.$template, $layout);    
        }
    }
```

Now on executing shell command

**$> cake email new_user_created**

It's returning me following error message.

*PHP Fatal error:  Class 'View' not found in C:\wamp\www\cakephp_application\app\Console\Command\EmailShell.php on line 22*

How do I get html of my email template so I can pass it to Mandril service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `View` is in the `View` folder, there isn't a Core folder.

You will want to use.
`App::uses('View', 'View');`