# CakePHP Shell Cronjob TCPDF

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, cron, tcpdf

**I'm using CakePHP 2.4 in and TCPDF to generate invoices.**

- A cronjob checks every day if new invoices shoot be generated.
- When I access the function via a browser, everything works perfect.
- When i access the function via the shell, I get an error:

**CronjobShell.php:**

```
$cmsoptions = $this->Cmsoption->find('first');
$this->set(compact('data', 'cmsoptions'));
$this->layout = 'pdf';
$this->render();
```

**"Call to undefined method CronjobShell::set()"**

**I understand that the Set option is ginving the problem. But how can I generate the PDF with a Cronjob?**

Comment: you can try it like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634102/cakephp-rendering-view-in-shell-is-not-working you need a reference to a view class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `AppShell` doesn't support view functional by default. So like in [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634102/cakephp-rendering-view-in-shell-is-not-working), you have to add following:

```
App::uses('View', 'Core');

$view = new View();
$view->set(compact('data', 'cmsoptions'));
$view->layout = 'pdf';
$pdfContent = $view->render();
```

And then you can use `$pdfContent` as content of PDF file with help of `file_put_contents('/var/www/new_invoice.pdf', $pdfContent);` or similar.

Comment: It works! I only had to point to the correct render file: `$view->render('Orders/add_orders');` Thanks!